# graphql resolver return Cannot return null for non-nullable field from asynchronous function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, async.js

Don't get me wrong I have been forced to use waterfall because I need to execute one function after another. There is no problem related to the schema or return type just stuck with asynchronous waterfall. All I need is to return from the final function not before.

```
const async = require('async')
module.exports = {
logout : ()=>{
        return async.waterfall([
            callback => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let data = 1;
                    return callback(null, data)
                }, 2000);
            },
            (data, callback) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return callback(null, data+1)
                }, 2000);
            }
            
        ], (err, res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            return res
        })
    }
}
```

response from graphiql because It returns early. And console.log is working

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field RootMutation.logout.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "logout"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use async/await here? Along the lines of the below

```js
async function logout(){
       let data = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {setTimeout(() => { resolve(1)},2000)});
       
         data = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {setTimeout(() => { resolve(data + 1)},2000)});
return data;
}

async function foo() {
    let res = await logout();
  alert(res)
}

foo()
```

Also I'm not familiar with the async library, but should you actually be returning the `async.waterfall()` call in your example as that returns `undefined` according to the docs.

Perhaps just

```
const async = require('async')
module.exports = {
logout : ()=>{
        async.waterfall([
            callback => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let data = 1;
                    return callback(null, data)
                }, 2000);
            },
            (data, callback) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return callback(null, data+1)
                }, 2000);
            }
            
        ], (err, res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            return res
        })
    }
}
```

If not perhaps share what GraphQL library you are using as well